# Erro ao gerar código de barras em PHP

Tags: php

Bom, meu problema é um seguinte:

Tenho a linha digitável e quero transformá-lá em código de barras.

Vocês devem estar pensando: "*nossa isso é bem simples usando algumas classes prontas que tem na web!*".

Pois é, já testei diversos modelos e ao fazer a leitura do código de barras gerado é interpretado com outros números. No início até fica igual, mas em certas partes do código ele altera, mas não faço ideia o motivo disso.

Quem puder me ajudar, eu ficaria muito grato. Preciso muito resolver esse problema.

**EXEMPLO:**

Linha digitável para conversão:

> 846100000005919402962014711150030007003147180834

O que está gerando:

> 846100000005591940296203147111500301007003147183

```
<?php
function geraCodigoBarra($numero){
    $fino = 1;
    $largo = 3;
    $altura = 50;

    $barcodes[0] = '00110';
    $barcodes[1] = '10001';
    $barcodes[2] = '01001';
    $barcodes[3] = '11000';
    $barcodes[4] = '00101';
    $barcodes[5] = '10100';
    $barcodes[6] = '01100';
    $barcodes[7] = '00011';
    $barcodes[8] = '10010';
    $barcodes[9] = '01010';

    for($f1 = 9; $f1 >= 0; $f1--){
        for($f2 = 9; $f2 >= 0; $f2--){
            $f = ($f1*10)+$f2;
            $texto = '';
            for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
                $texto .= substr($barcodes[$f1], ($i-1), 1).substr($barcodes[$f2] ,($i-1), 1);
            }
            $barcodes[$f] = $texto;
        }
    }

    echo '<img src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
    echo '<img src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
    echo '<img src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
    echo '<img src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';

    echo '<img ';

    $texto = $numero;

    if((strlen($texto) % 2) <> 0){
        $texto = '0'.$texto;
    }

    while(strlen($texto) > 0){
        $i = round(substr($texto, 0, 2));
        $texto = substr($texto, strlen($texto)-(strlen($texto)-2), (strlen($texto)-2));

        if(isset($barcodes[$i])){
            $f = $barcodes[$i];
        }

        for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i+=2){
            if(substr($f, ($i-1), 1) == '0'){
                $f1 = $fino ;
            }else{
                $f1 = $largo ;
            }

            echo 'src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$f1.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0">';
            echo '<img ';

            if(substr($f, $i, 1) == '0'){
                $f2 = $fino ;
            }else{
                $f2 = $largo ;
            }

            echo 'src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$f2.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0">';
            echo '<img ';
        }
    }
    echo 'src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$largo.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
    echo '<img src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
    echo '<img src="imagens/p.gif" width="1" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
}

geraCodigoBarra('846100000005919402962014711150030007003147180834');
?>
```

Comment: Como é que retorna isso em números em vez de imagens?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi sua pergunta. Pois o que me retorna é esse numero : 846100000005591940296203147111500301007003147183

Comment: Ao reproduzir seu código, retorna uma barra de códigos em imagens. Gostaria de ver o número referente a essa barra.

Comment: Sim amigo, é esse mesmo que coloquei... quando o leitor faz a leitura do código de barras, ele lê  e me mostra esse numero: 846100000005591940296203147111500301007003147183

Comment: Entendi, mas como faz pra retornar esse número sem leitor?

Comment: Esse numero eu obtive por meio de um leitor, e também tem um site que converte a linha digitável em código de barras  e já mostra a os numeros que representam o código de barras gerado. O que eu não consigo entender é que peço pra gerar emcima de uma linha digitavél... e acaba transformando em outra....

Site mencionado: https://www.free-barcode-generator.net/2of5-interleaved/

Comment: Testei o código gerado no leitor do telefone e retornou o mesmo número.

Comment: Seu leitor deve estar com defeito. Fiz a leitura no telefone e voltou o mesmo número. Fiz a leitura num site que lê cód. de barras online e voltou o mesmo número: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVg1R.jpg

Comment: nossa sério...? vc pediu pra gerar o código de barras por esse numero: 846100000005919402962014711150030007003147180834  ?

consegue mandar uma imagem do codigo de barras gerado por gentileza.

Comment: Tá no link da imagem do meu último comentário.

Comment: Fiz a leitura da sua imagem e me retornou outro numero...
846100000005591940296203147111500301007003147183
Da mesma forma que esta acontecendo em minha aplicação,

Comment: Testa em outro código de barras, de alguma embalagem aí pra ver se retorna o mesmo número.

Comment: Então esse código de barras eu gero para realizar pagamento... fará parte de um boleto, então quando estou tentando realizar leitura, estou fazendo pelo app do banco, estou te dizendo isso pq testei com um app de leitor de codigo de barras, e ele realmente faz a leitura do numero certo, porém nos app de bancos, esta acontecendo o problema mencionado.

Comment: Sim, qnd faz a leitura, ele vira aquele numero diferente que postei.